# Reading weekday data in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to read a date format in R, but it does not handle the weekday (first thing).
This is what I tried so far:

```
as.Date('Tue Feb  8 19:56:28 2022', format = "%a %b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

This works fine:

```
as.Date('Feb  8 19:56:28 2022', format = "%b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: I thought about using grep or sub by just killing the weekday/ the first 3 letters and the space from the string.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. `as.Date('Tue Feb  8 19:56:28 2022', format = "%a %b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y")` this returns "2022-02-08".  I am wondering if it has something to do with your locale.  Run `Sys.getlocale()` and see if it returns an English language location.

Comment: Yes, this made the trick: Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")